# CRON not starting my python script on reboot

Tags: linux, cron

Problem: unable to make my python script run on reboot

I edit `/etc/crontab` with Nano

Edited file to read (left all default text in file)

```
@reboot root screen -d -m -S Rusty /root/rustynail.py
```

Looking through this website I see a lot of reference to PATH.
As I have the full path specified I don't see this as the issue.
Happy to be proved wrong.

I have tested screen by changing the CRONTAB to

```
@reboot root screen -d -m -S rusty ping 8.8.8.8
```

This works as expected

The script runs fine when i am logged in as root.
Tried changing shell to shell/bin/bash.

Other things in CRONTAB work fine.
I have an rsync start daily
and a mount.cifs on reboot.

I have set log directories and looked in `/var/log/syslog`,
using command `grep CRON var/log/syslog`

output =

```
(root) cmd (screen -d -m -S rusty /root/rustynail.py
```

Any thought will be greatly appreciated
Noob to Linux, so sorry if obvious one.

---

Okay, so after further testing i have found this.
If I use `crontab -e` and set the python script to run every minute

```
"* * * * *" screen -d -m /root/rustynail.py  >> /var/log/myscript.log 2?&1
```

It works as expected! I think this proves its not a PATH or BASH problem.

If I replace `* * * * *` with `@reboot screen -d -m.. ... . .. etc`
It does not work.

My first thought was, the screen is being created and the script run before the network card is up, thus when the script tried to send data to an external address it fails, causing the script to stop and the screen window to close.

BUT

I have another `@reboot` after the script one that `mounts.cifs` to my NAS, that one works fine everytime.
Please, any thoughts welcome.

Comment: Did you try using `crontab -e` to install the task?

Comment: Did you install the crontab as root or as simple user?

Comment: I use nano /etc/crontab.  Dont use crontab -e to edit.  Not sure if i installed CRONTAB, thought it was part of the OS. thx for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by putting 30 second delay in Python script before it started doing anything
Guess problem must be something to do with something not being ready before script runs.
Hope this helps someone else

Thanks to anyone who spent time on this question

Comment: I generally do this right in the crontab to avoid changing all other calls to my scripts; just make the command be `sleep 30 && /root/rustynail.py` and it should work without impacting other calls to your script.